# Я учусь программировать на React, я делаю соц. сеть по одному курсу, сегодня тема Props

Tags: reactjs, build-error

Вот часть когда  с Props,

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQhw5.png]

но мне выдает ошибку

> ./src/components/Profile/Post/Post.jsx
> Line 8:14:  'props' is not defined  no-undef
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Что делать?

Comment: вы так компоненты создаете?

Comment: да, я подробил свой проект на компоненты

Comment: Не подскажите, как "похвалить" вас здесь?

Comment: отметьте ответ как решение)

Comment: Прочитай правила сайта [tour] для начала.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Укажите, что Post получает данные в качестве параметра `const Post = (props) => {}`